# storing images in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

i am trying to code a chrome extension that shows the bookmarks in an html page having the name, url and thumbnail of the tab.
So far i got the JS to capture the tab thumbnail in a PNG format but now i need to store it somewhere so when i open the extension's page the images could be there.

```
$scope.getPageThumbnail = function() {
  chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab(null, {format: 'png'}, function(img)
    {
      $scope.img = img;
    }
  );
};
```

Is there a way to store images inside the extension so if the extension is removed, everything is deleted? 
Thank you in advance, Daniel.

Answer (score 1):

You can store in localstorage as a data URL. Depending on how you are generating your thumbnail, you might try the Canvas toDataURL API. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL

Answer (score 0):

You can use [HTML5 FileSystem APIs](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/) to save your images to a target directory (say you want them inside the extension, you can create a directory with a unique id).

If your option is not limited to chrome extensions, you can write an chrome app, and then [chrome.fileSystem](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/fileSystem) is available to you.